# Give a "smart" way to number an array

Tags: python, arrays, function, indexing

I have this problem where i want to give an ID number to each element in array. For example:

```
# case 1 
#points              z            f 
#index:      0   1   2   3   4    5    6   7   8   9   10
#ID:        -2  -1   0   1   2   -8   -7  -6  -5  -4  -3

# case 2
#points              f            z 
#index:      0   1   2   3   4    5    6   7   8   9   10
#ID:         6   7  -3  -2  -1    0    1   2   3   4   5
```

where f is a variable that stores the index of "first" element and z is a variable that stores the trigger index "zero".

What i want is a smart method to calculate these IDs as you see in the example. I know that this is really simple using is and else statements, but i want something more cleen. something that will work like this:

```
n_samples = None
first  = None
zero = None

def index(i):
    ID = None
    
    # Your solution

    return ID
    
for i in range(0, n_samples):
    print(index(i))
```

Comment: You need to be bit more clear about what exactly is your input and how you are constructing the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift indices so that `first` goes to index zero and use modulo to wrap them around:

```
def index(i):

    i = (i - first) % n_samples
    z = (zero - first) % n_samples
    ID = i - z

    return ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use numpy functions for that.
`np.where` returns indices that satisfy the condition, and `np.argmin` returns an index of the minimum.

For example:

```
case1 = [-2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,   -8,   -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3]
case2 = [6,   7,  -3,  -2,  -1,    0,    1,   2,   3,   4,   5]

print(np.where(np.array(case1) == 0)[0][0], np.argmin(case1))
print(np.where(np.array(case2) == 0)[0][0], np.argmin(case2))
```

Output:

```
2 5
5 2
```